# Angular JS firebase.(child_added) not rendering on page

Tags: angularjs, firebase

I have entries in my firebase database that I am trying to get to show up on the html page. The console.log shows the children in the database, but it is not displaying on the page. Here is the code I have:

DB:

```
quiz-show  
    user
        -JuYaVjjm0zY59vK48aR: "user1"
        -JuYaXzrT2-_pfhpr58o: "user2"
        -JuYaZd_oS-hi5zqYLhX: "user3"
        -JuYaaNNd24Icruv18LH: "user4"
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('phoneQuizAnswer')
    .controller('testCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseObject) {
        var fireRef = new Firebase('https://[myfirebase]/users');
        $scope.h1 = 'responses:';
        fireRef.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val());
            $scope.users = childSnapshot.val();
        });
    });
```

html:

```
{{h1}}
{{users}}
```

console.log shows

```
user1
user2
user3
....
```

`{{h1}}` renders correctly, but `{{users}}` does not render anything. So how can I get each to show up on the page?

Comment: Have you tried {{users | json}}?

Comment: Yeah, that doesnt seem to work either

Comment: I put in this $scope.users = $firebaseObject(fireRef); and that seems to render on the page. So it is not liking something about $scope.users = childSnapshot.val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firebase asynchronously loads and monitors data. Whenever (new or updated) data is available, your callback function is fired. Unfortunately at that point, AngularJS typically isn't ready to accept the changes anymore. That's why Firebase created AngularFire, which automatically notifies AngularJS when changes happen.

You seem to be partially using AngularFire, but not for this construct. I recomment *either always* using AngularFire for data that needs to be bound to the `$scope` *or never* using AngularFire. The choice is yours, but be consistent.

Using AngularFire:

```
        var fireRef = new Firebase('https://[myfirebase]/users');
        $scope.h1 = 'responses:';
        $scope.users = $firebaseArray(fireRef);
```

Not using AngularFire:

```
        var fireRef = new Firebase('https://[myfirebase]/users');
        $scope.h1 = 'responses:';
        fireRef.on('value', function(childSnapshot, prevChildKey) {
          $timeout(function() {
            console.log(childSnapshot.val());
            $scope.users = childSnapshot.val();
          };
        });
```

The `$timeout` construct tells AngularFire that you're modifying the `$scope`.

Note that binding arrays to the scope is covered in every piece of [AngularFire documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/) we have: [the AngularFire quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html#section-arrays), [the AngularFire guide](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/synchronized-arrays.html) and the [AngularFire API docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasearray). Please read them, they contain many other useful bits.

Comment: Thanks for getting me there! I will go threw those docs. I had to use <li ng-repeat="user in users">{{ user.$value }}</li> to drill down to just the user. Thanks!