# Angular JS - Iterate array of objects obtained from a Firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building an app that gets its objects from a Firebase database. The problem is that when I try to iterate what I got, it doesn't show anything. However, when I ask to display it via `console.log` it's there! 
I guess it is because of an HTTP method and its promise. But I haven't figured out how to solve it. Could someone please help me understand it?

HTML:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Options</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
      <td>{{profile.value.id}}</td>
      <td>{{profile.value.name}}</td>
      <td>{{profile.value.description}}</td>
      <td>{{profile.value.price | currency}}</td>
      <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn">Edit</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller.js

```
App.controller("adminController", function($scope) {
  console.log("running");

  var profiles = new Array;

  var query = firebase.database().ref("profiles").orderByKey();

  query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();

        profiles.push({
          key: key,
          value: JSON.parse(childData)
        })
    });
    console.log(profiles);
  });
}
```

Comment: The data is being added to `profiles` at a moment that AngularJS is not expecting it. Wrap the callback in `$timeout()` to make it aware. See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496266/angular-js-firebase-child-added-not-rendering-on-page/31496985#31496985

Answer (score 2):

You need to use **`$scope.profiles`** with your controller,

```
App.controller("adminController", function($scope) {
  console.log("running");
  $scope.profiles = [];
  var query = firebase.database().ref("profiles").orderByKey();
  query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var key = childSnapshot.key;
        var childData = childSnapshot.val();
        $scope.profiles.push({
          key: key,
          value: JSON.parse(childData)
        })
    });
    console.log($scope.profiles);
  });
}
```

Comment: I fixed it as you said but now I get this message on console: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. If I initiate it before pushing, it shows an empty array :(

Comment: check if you have the values

Comment: when I push it as I had written above, it shows after a few seconds the result (due to the HTTP promise, probably). But, if I push it into `$scope.profiles` it gives an error. I'm probably struggling with HTTP methods and angular itself

Comment: Probably, but this is how you need to proceed inorder to bind with the HTML